# How to read and modify a (.gct) file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, file-handling

Which libraries would help me read a gct file in python and edit it like removing the rows with NaN values. And how will the following code change if I apply it to a .gct file?

```
data = pd.read_csv('PAAD1.csv')
new_data = data.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
print("Old data frame length:", len(data), "\nNew data frame length:",  
       len(new_data), "\nNumber of rows with at least 1 NA value: ", 
       (len(data)-len(new_data)))
new_data.to_csv('EditedPAAD.csv')
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code for .gct file? Have you faced any issue you would need help with?

Comment: I don't know which function to use for reading gct files, like for CSV files it's read_csv(), what should I use for gct files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`cmapPy`](https://cmappy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package for this. Compared to `read_csv` it gives you more freedom and domain specific utilities. E.g. if your `*.gct` looks like this

```
#1.2            
22215   2       
Name    Description Tumor_One   Normal_One
1007_s_at   na  -0.214548   -0.18069
1053_at "RFC2 : replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa |@RFC2|"    0.868853    -1.330921
117_at  na  1.124814    0.933021
121_at  PAX8 : paired box gene 8 |@PAX8|    -0.825381   0.102078
1255_g_at   GUCA1A : guanylate cyclase activator 1A (retina) |@GUCA1A|  -0.734896   -0.184104
1294_at UBE1L : ubiquitin-activating enzyme E1-like |@UBE1L|    -0.366741   -1.209838
1316_at "THRA : thyroid hormone receptor, alpha (erythroblastic leukemia viral (v-erb-a) oncogene homolog, avian) |@THRA|"  -0.126108   1.486972
1320_at "PTPN21 : protein tyrosine phosphatase, non-receptor type 21 |@PTPN21|" 3.083681    -0.086705
...
```

You can extract only rows with a desired probeset id (row id), e.g. `['1007_s_at', '1053_at', '117_at', '121_at', '1255_g_at', '1294_at UBE1L']`

So to read a file, remove the `nan` in the `description` and save it again, do:

```
from cmapPy.pandasGEXpress.parse_gct import parse
from cmapPy.pandasGEXpress.write_gct import write

data = parse('example.gct', rid=['1007_s_at', '1053_at',
                                 '117_at', '121_at',
                                 '1255_g_at', '1294_at  UBE1L'])
# remove nan values from row_metadata (description column)
data.row_metadata_df.dropna(inplace=True)
# remove the entries of .data_df where nan values are in row_metadata
data.data_df = data.data_df.loc[data.row_metadata_df.index]

# Can only write GCT version 1.3
write(data, 'new_example.gct')
```

The `new_example.gct` looks then like this:

```
#1.3
3   2   1   0
id  Description Tumor_One   Normal_One

1053_at RFC2 : replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa |@RFC2|  0.8689  -1.3309

121_at  PAX8 : paired box gene 8 |@PAX8|    -0.8254 0.1021

1255_g_at   GUCA1A : guanylate cyclase activator 1A (retina) |@GUCA1A|  -0.7349 -0.1841
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!! Can you share where would I find all the functions I can use for gct files like plotting them in a cmap and things like that?Thanks again

Comment: Once you have the data in `data.data_df` you can use any plotting routine you want, e.g. `matplotlib`. E.g. a 2D histogram of `Tumor_one` vs. `Normal_one` would be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.hist2d(data.data_df['Tumor_One'], data.data_df['Normal_One'])`.

Comment: Is there any way i can get the count of the deleted number of rows because the len() function is not working on the files?

Comment: Also, the code you've given is just removing the NA values but not NaN values

Comment: regarding the counts: You have to apply the `len()` function on `data.data_df` and not on `data`. Regarding the NaN values: Do the `nan`s only appear in column `Description` or also in columns `Tumor_one` or `Normal_one`?

Comment: The file has a lot of columns and nan appears in many of them

Comment: I removed the `rid[]` part in the parse code you gave. I actually have a file with about 18000 rows and approx 4000 of them have at least one `NaN` value, I want to remove such rows and give their exact count also

Comment: @VihaanMisra, check https://cmappy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandasGEXpress.html to get list of funtions

Answer (score 0):

Quick search in google will give you the following:
https://pypi.org/project/cmapPy/

Regarding to the code, if you don't care about the metadata in the 2 first rows, it seems to work for your purpose, but you should first indicate that the delimiter is `TAB` and skip the 2 first rows - `pandas.read_csv(PATH_TO_GCT_FILE, sep='\t',skiprows=2)`

Comment: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 184`

Comment: How should i share the file with you?

Comment: Now I see. The `read_csv` will not help here unless you start read the file from row 3 - `skiprows=2`. The 2 first row in the data are metadata.